# javascript's different extend methods

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, javascript-objects

What is the difference between extend methods in JavaScript?

Let's say we have the following classes:

```
var BaseClass = function() {
    this.class_name = 'BaseClass';

    this.foo = function() {
        return 'foo';
    }

    this.sub = {
        moreStuff: 'weeee'
    }
};

BaseClass.prototype.bar = function () {
    return 'To be or not to be';
}

var SubClass = function() {
    this.class_name = 'SubClass';

    this.bar = function() {
        return 'bar';
    }

    this.sub = {
        moreStuff: 'wooohooo'
    }
};
```

#### Method A:

```
SubClass.prototype = new BaseClass();
SubClass.prototype.constructor = SubClass;
```

#### Method B (from underscore.js):

```
_.extend = function(obj) {
    each(slice.call(arguments, 1), function(source) {
        if (source) {
            for (var prop in source) {
                obj[prop] = source[prop];
            }
        }
    });
    return obj;
};
```

#### Method C (from LiveScript):

```
function extend$(sub, sup){
    function fun(){}
    fun.prototype = (sub.superclass = sup).prototype;

    (sub.prototype = new fun).constructor = sub;

    if (typeof sup.extended == 'function') sup.extended(sub);

    return sub;
}
```

Method A looks simpler. Why go through the trouble of copying the object, one property at a time?

Comment: A is setting up inheritance and B is merging the properties of multiple objects into a target object. They have different purposes. I wouldn't describe A as an "extend method".

Comment: Ok, so it's not actually the same thing... can you describe a scenario where you would rather want one than the other?

Comment: You should look into `Object.create()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: Inheritance: If you really have an inheritance relationship between objects/constructor functions. E.g. a `Dog` *is an* `Animal`. Merging: If you have a configurations object supplied at runtime and want to make sure that it contains a fixed set of default settings.

Comment: [`_.extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) is usually used to merge two objects that are being used as simple key/value data structures. There's also [`_.defaults`](http://underscorejs.org/#defaults) which is more or less the same except for how overwrites are handled.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Method A looks simpler but using it you can inherit only from one object. What if you want your SubClass to inherit from `BaseClassOther` as well. In this case you should go for the Method B ( to inherit from `BaseClassOther` as well). 
You can not do 
`SubClass.prototype = new BaseClassOther();`
again this will overwrite prototype property.

Please have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Answer (score 0):

In Method A, in other circumstances, BaseClass() might be written to require an argument and to fail if it does not receive a valid one. The other two methods are not bothered by this. Perhaps the inherited constructors you are working with are not bothered by this either.